# Countdowntimer problems (not counting down correctly)

Tags: android, timer

Having some issues with my countdown timer.  Im basically have a spinner that has set values in it.  Here is the code for the spinner:

```
tSpin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            if(i == 0){
                timeInms1 = 8400000;
            }
           if (i == 1){
                timeInms1 = 13200000;
            }
           if (i == 2){
                timeInms1 = 18000000;
            }
            if(i == 3){
                timeInms1 = 22800000;
            }
            if(i == 4){
                timeInms1 = 27600000;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

I then wanted to pass the choice to a count down timer to have the timer count down a given amount of time based on the choice the user made previously in the spinner.  Heres the code for the count down timer:

```
 final CountDownTimer lumbyTree = new CountDownTimer(timeInms1,1000) {


        @Override
        public void onTick(long lumbyTreeTimeToGo) {
            int mins = (int)lumbyTreeTimeToGo/60000;
            int seconds = (int)(lumbyTreeTimeToGo-(mins*60000))/1000;
            tTimer1.setText(mins +":" +seconds);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            tTimer1.setText("00:09");
        }
    };

    tStart1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lumbyTree.start();

        }
    });
```

The problem is, I think the 'timeInms1' variable never gets a value for some reason.  The timer goes straight to the onFinish method.  I put some random test statements into the spinner's 'if' brackets to make sure it was functioning correctly (such as changing text in a textView) and it functioned as expected, what was in the brackets were carried out correctly.  I also tried initializing timeInms1 with a random value (such as 30000) and it runs, but isnt changed, it just runs the timer for 30 seconds.  It puzzles me that when I put code such as setText in the 'spinner's' brackets it would execute, but when I go to change the value of 'TimeInms1' it doesnt work.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: You want to start timer as soon as spinner choice is made?

Comment: No, I have a button that runs the .start() command. The button is labled tStart1.  It is the last method listed. ive tested it and it works, when i press it, it goes to the onFinish method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MainActivity .java should look something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
CountDownTimer lumbyTree;
    Textview tTimer1;
int timeInms1;

private void createCountDownTimer() {
    lumbyTree = new CountDownTimer(timeInms1,1000) {

        @Override
    public void onTick(long lumbyTreeTimeToGo) {
        int mins = (int)lumbyTreeTimeToGo/60000;
        int seconds = (int)(lumbyTreeTimeToGo-(mins*60000))/1000;
        tTimer1.setText(mins +":" +seconds);
    }

        @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        tTimer1.setText("00:09");
    }
    };

}
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button tStart1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tStart1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createCountDownTimer();
            lumbyTree.start();

        }
    });
    Spinner tSpin1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    tSpin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


        if(i == 0){
            timeInms1 = 8400000;
        }
       if (i == 1){
            timeInms1 = 13200000;
        }
       if (i == 2){
            timeInms1 = 18000000;
        }
        if(i == 3){
            timeInms1 = 22800000;
        }
        if(i == 4){
            timeInms1 = 27600000;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
});
}
```

Comment: Just tried this and almost everything in my project now is underlined in red.  All with errors that say 'class' or 'interface' expected

Comment: Is lumbyTree a class variable or is it declared inside some function? Make it class variable(ie. declare outside any function). Also remove final while declaring lumbyTree

Comment: lumbyTree is declared under MainActivity.java.  I removed final and got the following error message : Variable 'lumbyTree' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be made final

Comment: You will only get that error if you have declare ie.final CountDownTimer lumbyTree = new CountDownTimer(timeInms1,1000) this line inside some function my guess is oncreate. It should be  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 CountDownTimer lumbyTree;    like this

Comment: So youre saying i need to create a whole new class file to host this timer?  (BTW this is one of 5 timers in the activity)  You are correct though, I did declare it under mainActiviy.  Thanks for bearing with me, im kinda new to this :P

Comment: No there is no need to create new class file I will update my answer and let you know

Comment: I have not initialize tTimer1. Please do so in your oncreate

Comment: Awesome!  That worked!  So for the other 5 timers do i have to go through the same process?  Would I need to declare 4 more adapters, onclick listeners and timers?  I would think so...

Comment: Got everything working (including the other 4 timers)  Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: Sorry I didnt see you comment before but glad I helped.